# Call method on object also do async operation before

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

i'm using a library that return an object with multiple keys and methods to use, one of the key of this object is accessToken.
accessToken value must exist before calling any method of this object (otherwise you're not authenticated).
The token is retrieved externally using an async axios function, also this token is only valid for 1 hour, in this case it's okay to get a new token every time you call some function inside it.

I dont' want to recreate the object every time i use this library (i'm using this library multiple times).

So far based on few articles i found online i did this:

```
const force = require('jsforce')
const { SFAuth } = require('./auth')
const common = require('../common')

class JSForce {
  constructor (connection) {
    return connection
  }

  static async Connect () {
    const token = await SFAuth.getToken()
    const connection = new force.Connection({
      instanceUrl: common.SALESFORCE_URL,
      accessToken: token
    })
    return new JSForce(connection)
  }
}

const start = async () => {
  const res = await JSForce.Connect()
  console.log(res)
}

start()
```

If i try to do JSForce.Connect().sobject('Account') i get an error saying  sobject is not a function.
It works if first i save JSFORCE.Connect() in a new instance and then i use this instance.sobject() but i can't do it every time i need to use it.
How would you solve this?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is field sobject will only come once you have JSForce connection successful. First we need to make sure we have that and we can save in variable. We will only call JSForce if we don't have instance already.
Declare a global variable in file.

```
let instance: <any>

// This method will return instance always if we dont have
const getInstance = async () => {
  if (!instance) {
    instance = await JSForce.Connect();
  }
  return instance;
};

const start = async () => {
  const res = await getInstance().sobject('Account');
  console.log(res);
}

start();
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, i tried to run your code and i still get TypeError: getInstance(...).sobject is not a function. In reality sobject is there (if you console log the object) but you can't call it unless first it gets copied in its own variable, unfortunately the problem seems to be the async call inside the class (i found multiple cases with the same problem).